# Too Many Lock Screens

Tags: kde, lock, kdm

I installed a few different GUI environments for Ubuntu 14.04 and I finally settled on KDE.

However, when I lock my desktop and come back to it I have to sign in twice... I have two different looking lock screens... Why? How do I heal this?

Answer (score 0):

If it is gdm and lightdm then do 'sudo apt-get remove --purge" to one of them, depending on the one you prefer

Answer (score 0):

You probably mean screensavers, and you have `xscreensaver` and some gtk/qt version installed. I would check in synaptics which screensavers you have installed, and remove all but one.